# SCR_EL3 configuration in VM (QEMU)

Tags: exception, raspberry-pi, arm, bare-metal

I'm trying to understand some assembly code to boot a Raspberry Pi 3B with QEMU (bare metal), but there are some things I don't understand for SCR_EL3 register. Here is the code:

```
   _start:
    // in QEMU all of 4 ARM CPUs are started simultaneously
    // by default. I don't know if this is the real hw behaviour,
    // but here I jump to halt if CPU ID (stored in MPIDR
    // register, first 2 bits) is not 0
    mrs   x1, mpidr_el1
    and   x1, x1, #3
    cmp   x1, #0
    bne   hang 

    // address for stack pointer
    ldr   x1, =_start

    // drop to EL2
    mov   x2, #0x5b1    // RW=1, HCE=1, SMD=1, RES=1, NS=1
    msr   scr_el3, x2
    mov   x2, #0x3c9    // D=1, A=1, I=1, F=1 M=EL2h
    msr   spsr_el3, x2
    adr   x2, start_el2
    msr   elr_el3, x2
    eret

start_el2:
    // set sp in EL1
    msr   sp_el1, x1
    // enable AArch64 in EL1
    mov   x0, #(1 << 31)      // AArch64
    orr   x0, x0, #(1 << 1)   // SWIO hardwired on Pi3
    msr   hcr_el2, x0
    mrs   x0, hcr_el2
    // set vector address in EL1.
    ldr x0, =vector
    msr vbar_el1, x0 
    // change execution level to EL1
    mov   x2, #0x3c4         // D=1, A=1, I=1, F=1 M=EL1t
    msr   spsr_el2, x2
    adr   x2, start_el1
    msr   elr_el2, x2
    eret

start_el1:
    // set sp
    mov   sp, x1
    // Clear bss.
    ldr   x1, =__bss_start
    ldr   w2, =__bss_size
1:  cbz   w2, 2f
    str   xzr, [x1], #8
    sub   w2, w2, #1
    cbnz  w2, 1b

2:  bl main
```

If I don't enable the HCE in scr_el3, the eret at the end of start_el2 won't work, why do this happen? the same for NS, if I set it as 0 it won't work ,but enabling security mode should give it more memory access no block eret. Then it set some bits in RES which is a reserved Space, couldn't find any reason. RW I know is for working on aarch64. On the other hard, spsr_el is configured to set IQR,FIQ amd SError after an exception return. Also return on EL2 when EL3 executes exception. Thanks for your feedback, it's a bit hard to understand how some configurations change behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

How were you able to boot qemu raspberrypi 3b in EL3 ? As per my understanding , the GPU firmware boots first and moves the system to EL2. So we will not be able to access any EL3 specific registers.